# Harmonic addition till 100

Tags: elementary-number-theory, harmonic-numbers

Question: $\boxed{\text{Consider $\sum_{i=1}^{100}\tfrac{1}{i}=\tfrac{A}{B}$.
Given that $\text{gcd}(A,B)=1$, 
Show that $5\nmid AB$}}$

Comment: If you use least common multiples, the denominator has only two factors of $5$ in it

Comment: The question doesn't say that $5 \not\mid AB$. It asks you to determine whether $5 \mid AB$ or $5 \not\mid AB$. It seems that you have determined that $5 \mid AB$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Well, well, the question said to show $5$ doesn't divide $AB$. Here, I have written the question differently to pose in front of you people. Anyway, I am editing it.

Comment: Numerical computations suggest that $5\nmid AB$, and that $AB\pmod{5} = 2$.

Comment: Based on this [Wolfram Alpha query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2Fn+from+n+%3D+1+to+100), it seems that $A$ and $B$ are not divisible by $5$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 It asks if their product is divisible or not. You claim that none of them is divisible right? Can you give me a reason?

Comment: All I did was type that sum into Wolfram Alpha and look at the fraction it gave as the answer. I have no mathematical justification to show that $5 \not\mid AB$.

Comment: Oh okay, fine fine

Comment: Okay, then no more solutions be posted. Thanks.